# Codeigniter : Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-login

I'm trying to develop facebook app with codeigniter. I'm using jondavidjohn's facebook api library. And i have created application on facebook. i got my app id and secret too. I wrote similar codes of example that is debugging user profile details. That's ok on my facebook. But when i test this app on other people's facebook everything returns 0. So what can be problem here? My codes are here: http://pastebin.ca/2460564. Regards.

Comment: You're asking for permissions before right?

Comment: Is ur app in development mode?

Comment: mates im sorry for late reply i ve solved it :)